# ¿Cómo puedo hacer la siguiente secuencia numérica en R?

Tags: r, bucles

Quiero realizar la siguiente secuencia:

1,1,2,2,3,3...100,100

sin escribir manualmente toda la secuencia, pero no lo logro.

¿Me pueden ayudar? lo agradezco mucho.

Saludos.

Comment: Muy importante agregar lo que trataste o investigaste , revisar [ask], saludos.

Answer (score 3):

Con la función `rep()`.

```
rep(1:100,each=2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Así por ejemplo:

```
v<-c(1:100,1:100)
v[order(v)]
```